# How to store a single \ in a string variable?

Tags: python

```
file_name = file_path.split('\')
```

Gives me an error because `\'` is to represent a single quote in python.

I want to split a file name using single backslash.

Comment: Have you heard of escape characters? And/or raw strings?

Comment: `'\\'` **is** a single backslash -- if you `print('\\')`, you'll see it only prints one backslash, not two.

Answer (score 2):

Use a double `\`:

```
file_name = file_path.split('\\')
```